# Laravel VueJS: building multi page app without resorting to single page application ( SPA ) approach

Tags: laravel, vue.js, multi-page-application

I am trying to build a Laravel 5.5 + VueJs multi page app. I do not want to use SPA (Single Page Application) approach to make it seem to be a multi page app.

This is the case with the registration page at the URL `/register`. With the command `php artisan make:auth` I get the registration related files. The scenarios is :

In `web.php`, I have :

```
Auth::routes();
```

In `app.js`, I have :

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        Register: require('./components/Register.vue')
    }
});
```

My `layout.blade.php` resides within `resources/views/` folder and has the following content :

```
    <div id="app">
    
                <?php
                  var_dump($component);
                ?>
                @if (isset($component))
                    <component :is={{ $component }} >
                        @endif
    
                        @yield('content')
    
                        @if (isset($component))
                    </component>
                @endif
   </div>
```

The `register.blade.php` file has the content :

```
@extends('layout', ['component' => 'Register'])

@section('content')
  
@endsection
```

`Register.vue` stays inside `resources/js/components/` and has the following content :

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example component!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Register Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

So my intended work flow is: first the `register.blade.php` will be called that inherits `layout.blade.php` and sends as data the `Register` component which is supposed to be rendered there.

**I myself also do not know how the `register.blade.php` will have the component `Register` as parameter in the data at the line :**

```
@extends('layout', ['component' => 'Register'])
```

**And while viewing the page source, I even do not see the `app.js` file being included in the page.**

Of course, I run the `npm run dev` command before testing the page every time.

**Question 1 :** What is wrong with the approach outlined above ? What should be the proper way however ?

**EDIT:**

My `webpack.mix.js` has:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
    mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
        .styles([
    
            'resources/assets/css/style.css'
    
        ], 'public/css/style.css')
    ;

mix.options({
    extractVueStyles: 'public/css/vue-style.css'
});
```

**EDIT2:**
In the page, I see no content from the `Register` component . I forgot to mention it before.

**EDIT3:**
**Question 2:** Is Laravel+VueJs combination not meant for MPA (multi page application) in true sense of the term ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's very easy to give an answer to your question, so I will share my experience. At the beginning I was implementing Vue.js in the same way you do so:

- Multipage app
- Every page has it's own components
- Every time the user moves to another page, potentially a new js file is loaded.

It was a complete failure. At the beginning I was using a single `app.js` file, but I was loading tons of useless components for a single form... Why do I have to load the whole application when I need only two or three components? So I had to create tons of `xxx-app.js` files and break the DRY principle. It wasn't the best... But it worked and was easy to implement.

**SIDE NOTE**: I wasn't using any kind of file chunking or other systems that may have removed this kind of problem. I was at the very beginning with VueJS development. Probably at the time I didn't even know it was possible.

The structure was something like:

**page1.blade.php**

```html
@extends('my.layout')

@push('scripts')
    <script src="asset('page1-app.js')"></script>
@endpush

@section('content')
    <page1-component attr1="{{ $attr1 }}" [...]></page1-component>
@endsection
```

As you can see the structure is kinda simple:

- Extend the required layout in order to load the CSS and extra scripts required
- Push in the `scripts` stack the Vue instance you need
- In the content section call the component you need

But the problems were born in the javascript part... I was using 1/3 of the features of modern javascript app development. Everyday a new problem was coming out... First JQuery was useless... Then the technical SEO part was hard to handle... Then the Vuex store logic was replicated and useless when the user reloads the page... In a very short time I realized that this approach was completely wrong...

Well, for the application I was working on at least. So IMHO and as in many cases the answer to your question

> What is wrong with the approach outlined above ? What should be the proper way however ?

is **It depends**.

If you have a small application, easy to maintain and without complex workflow, your solution works... You just have to remember that:

1. If you include in every page your `app.js` file but you need only 1 or 2 components it may become a little heavy.
2. There's a high risk of redundancy.
3. The initial components state depends on the backend attributes given to the blade view... If something is wrong, the entire application messes up.

If you're facing these problems consider to move to a complete SPA logic... Easier to maintain, you don't have to invent a workaround everyday and so on.

If your application is an "enterprise" solution... Well avoid to mix up Laravel and Vue in a single codebase... Split everything and handle the backend and the frontend as two completely separate entities.

Comment: ' Split everything and handle the backend and the frontend as two completely separate entities ' - how to do that ?

Comment: do you have any answer to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245577/laravel-vuejs-router-view-does-not-render-the-component   ? I tried to follow SPA but the problem in the question arose .

Comment: ' If you're facing these problems consider to move to a complete SPA logic ' - do you want to say that Laravel + VueJs combination is not meant for any MPA ( multi page application) in true sense of the term ?

Comment: multiple `EDIT`s are added in OP .

Comment: 1°: just create one project for Laravel and one for Vue (with Vue Cli for example)
2°: I will check that question another time
3°: exactly

Comment: 1°: how will the 2 entities interact ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have different vue js applications for the same laravel project.
The following was my approach:

1. Create different VueJs apps file eg. frontend.js, app.js, example.js
2. Edit the webpack.mix.js and add the app's files using the mix.js() function for each of the applications. Eg

   mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/js/frontend.js', 'public/js')
3. Add the app file to your blade using the mix function
   Eg. `<script src="{{ mix('js/frontend.js') }}"></script>`

The app should be working and rendering inside

```
<div id="app">
        <app></app>
    </div>
```